# HTML make text clickable without making it a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add the ability to have the option to click on certain HTML text and have the correct JavaScript code be executed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

For semantics I'd use a `<button>` element like this:

```html
<button class="link">Clicky</button>
```

to make the button look like normal text you can use CSS:

```css
button.link { background:none; border:none; }
```

and for easiness of handing click I'd use jQuery like so:

```js
$(".link").on("click", function(e) {
    // e is the event object
    // this is the button element
    // do stuff with them
});
```

Although if you have an ID attribute on the button you can use plain JS like this:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("your-button-id");
button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // e is the event object
    // e.target is the button element
    // do stuff with them
});
```

Comment: Too many pending edits on SO... I think you mean `background: transparent;`, `none` is not a valid value for a color.

Comment: @run_the_race `background: transparent` is equivalent to `background: none` which is also equivalent to `background: repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box none transparent;` ... `background` is shorthand for more than just `background-color` see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background#values

Answer (score 8):

```
<div id="text" onClick="function()"> your text here </div>
```

Comment: This is pretty ugly, unmaintainable, and not recommended since the turn of the century. Event listeners should always be declared in a separate script block or file.

Comment: Will not work with iOS

Answer (score 3):

The apropriate element for an interactive control that isn't a link somewhere is a `<button>Label</button>` or (`<input type="button" value="Label">`). (You can always style away the border and background with CSS).

You can bind a `click` event handler to it using the standard DOM APIs (or a library that abstracts them such as YUI or jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

place the text in a span or other element with a class `<span class="yourClass">text</span>` and then use javascript to add an event listener (preferably at the end of your html. for brevity, I'll demonstrate with jQuery, though it could be done with native javascript.

```
<script>
  $('.yourClass').on('click',function(){
    //your javacript
  });
</script>
```

Alternatively you could do search through all the page for instances of that word, though I would not recommend that as it would really slow things down.

Comment: Don't use a span. They aren't designed to be interactive, so if someone navigates to them using a linear input device (e.g. a keyboard user, or someone using one of numerous pieces of AT) then the focus will skip over it. Using a span is an unneeded accessibility barrier.