# Making a part of an uploaded text file as clickable using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, onclick, highlight

I uploaded one file using javascript. I want to make some parts of the text file as highlighted as well as clickable. For example: I want to make all the "hello" in the uploaded file as clickable and highlighted.

I am able to highlight the text as i have used button tag and changed its background and border property in css but I am unable to do an onclick action when the button is clicked.

I tried it like this:

```
var sel_data=$("#sel").text(); // for taking the text file in avariable

var str='hello';

//making the regular expression of str
var re = new RegExp(str,"g");

//For replacing the 'str' by highlighted and clickable 'str'
var re_str="<button class='highlight' id='ty' onclick='alertfunc()' value="+str+">"+str+"</button>"

//replacement of 'str' by highlighted and clickable 'str'
var rep_data=sel_data.replace(re,re_str);
sel_data=rep_data;

//function to be executed when the button will get clicked
function alertfunc() {
    alert('yellow');
}
```

I also tried it like this

```
var str='hello'


var re_str="<button class='highlight' id='ty'  value="+str+">"+str+"</button>" 

$(".highlight").click(function(){
     alert("yellow");
})
```

or like this

```
var button = document.getElementById("ty");
button.onclick = function(){
alert("yellow");
}
```

But none of them is working  , Please suggest
I referred the above examples by this link: [Html make text clickable without making it a hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467504/html-make-text-clickable-without-making-it-a-hyperlink)

Comment: How do you output the "text file" ? What do you do with your `re_str` variable ? Where are you trying to replace the occurences of a word with a button ? Your question is incomplete or quite unclear.

Comment: I have edited and clarfied all the things that you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are just a few things wrong here.
First, execute this code on document ready :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // code
});
```

Then, update the actual html in the DOM :

```
//replacement of 'str' by highlighted and clickable 'str'
var rep_data=sel_data.replace(re,re_str);
sel_data=rep_data;
$("#sel").html(sel_data); // here
```

And use event delegation for the click :

```
$("#sel").on('click', '.highlight', function(){
     alert("yellow");
});
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gzv8p7op/)**

Answer (score 0):

This is done by using jQuery library and the ready snippet :contains.
Here is the code you need:

```
jQuery.fn.highlight = function (str, className) {
    var regex = new RegExp(str, "gi");
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).contents().filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType == 3 && regex.test(this.nodeValue);
        }).replaceWith(function() {
            return (this.nodeValue || "").replace(regex, function(match) {
                return "<span class=\"" + className + "\">" + match + "</span>";
            });

        });
    });
};
```

Using this snippet will lead the words "hello" to be wrapped around a span with class of your choice.

Now to call this function all you need to do is:

```
$(".testHighlight *").highlight("hello", "highlight");
```

Ofcourse you have to setup the .testHighlight class with CSS to be something like:

```
.testHighlight {
     background:yellow;
}
```

To make them clickable you can do it easily with jQuery:

```
$(.testHighlight).click(function(){
//YOUR CODE HERE
});
```

You can check more on this snippet [here](http://www.gotoquiz.com/web-coding/programming/javascript/highlight-words-in-text-with-jquery/).

Comment: I believe you function is used top highlight the text but that I have achieved using button tag , the main problem is how to perform an on click operation when I click on that button